# I don't understand RidgeCV's fit_intercept, and how to use it for my data

Tags: regression, linear-regression

Alright, I have an assignment that makes me calculate weights for a function with different terms. At first, I thought I might just leave the weight for the term $1$ out, and instead use the intercept. I have decided to use RidgeCV, as I had a large amount of multicolinearity.

However, now I have appended my $x$ by a row of $1$'s, and did the following:

```
RidgeCV(fit_intercept = False).fit(x, y)
```

Alright, now I have an array of weights. For comparison, I have tried also

```
RidgeCV(fit_intercept = True).fit(x, y)
```

As expected, the weight for $1$ became 0. However, all other values changed too - and the intercept is different from the weight for $1$ from before. I have also a different .score() - the first one is higher.

Why is that the case? I thought all fit_intercept was doing is adding a row of $1$ to my $x$, which obviously can't be true. Also, should I try centering my data myself, or is that now unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weight on the constant column was *also* penalized by Ridge, whereas the intercept fitted directly is not.

To your second question: Centering shouldn't be necessary (except maybe for computational reasons), though scaling is still recommended so that coefficient penalties are applied more equally.